# Inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY while updating blob in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to update a column named Body in my LetterTemplate table. But whenever I try to execute my query, the error shows : Inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

My code:

```
public static void UpdatData(OracleConnection connection, int mailId, byte[] sData)
{
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("UPDATE LetterTemplate SET " + "BODY = :BODY WHERE ID = :ID ", connection);

    OracleParameter blobParameter = new OracleParameter();

    blobParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob;
    blobParameter.ParameterName = "BODY";
    blobParameter.Value = sData;

    OracleParameter mailIDParameter = new OracleParameter();

    mailIDParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
    mailIDParameter.ParameterName = "ID";
    mailIDParameter.Value = mailId;
    //command.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = mailId;
    //command.Parameters.Add("BODY", OracleDbType.Blob, sData.Length).Value = sData;

    command.Parameters.Add(mailIDParameter);
    command.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);

    //connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


}
```

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726776/how-to-update-a-blob-column-error-ora-00932-while-insert-works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By carefully observing your code, I found that the sequence of adding the parameters is different from the variable declared. As a result, it was trying to set `mailIDParameter` to the Body, resulting in that error.

Try to swap the lines like this:

your code:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add(mailIDParameter);
command.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);
```

changed code:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);
command.Parameters.Add(mailIDParameter);
```

Hope you problem is solved